# Algorithm to calculate local Hölder exponent for discrete signal in matlab

Tags: matlab, wavelets

The formula of Hölder local exponent is as follows:

$$|f(x)-f(y)| < C.|x-y|^\alpha   ,\ \ \ \  \forall\  x,y\in  B(x_0,r), $$
$\ C  \  constant,$

if $f(x)$ doesn't have a derivative and it is continuous in the same local area centered at $x_0$.

if $f(x)$ have a $p$ derivative
$$ |d^pf(x)-d^pf(y)| < C.|x-y|^\alpha  $$

How to calculate the local Holder exponent **$\alpha(x_0)$** for discrete function (matlab) with  DWT wavelet?

Note: point-wise Hölder is calculated in wavelet algorithm with CWT coiflet..
(vanishing moment wavelet), not Hurst Exponent

Comment: I have stationnary random process. how estimate holder exponent ?

Comment: As stated the Question doesn't make much sense.  "How [to] calculat[e]" something can only be addressed if the input is specified.  You appear to have a "digital signal", possibly a discretely defined function, in which case there is nothing rigorous that can be said about the "local Hölder exponent".  In particular your "formula" fails to include the role of $C$, which is supposed to be positive and independent of $x,y$.